# Problemas con webpack

Tags: nodejs, webpack, gulp, babel

saludes estructure un proyecto con babel , sass y gulp a la hora de empaquetar recibo este **error**.

- Estoy en ubuntu 18.
- node: v9.8.0 gulp-cli : 2.0.1

a continuacion muestro las dependencias del proyecto

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.8.0"
  }
```

a continuación muestro el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de preferencia que el error sea texto

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los errores deben ir como texto en tu pregunta. Creo que van a necesitar saber la estructura de tu webpack para poder ayudarte

Comment: Muestra el error en texto (no solo la captura de pantalla), segundo incluye la app.js